# Detect chrome browsers language in selenium C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to detect the chrome browsers current language as i have to run my tests in 2 different languages.

I found 2 questions related to this, but they are from 2011 and in java, which didnt help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you can get it by executing a command in the browser console. Source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language)

```
public class Tests 
{
    public WebDriver driver;       

    [Test]
    public void TestGetBrowserLanguage()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("-lang=fr-ca"); //set the browser language

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");

        //get the browser language
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        var language = js.ExecuteScript("return window.navigator.language");

        driver.Quit();

    }

}
```